# MySQL foreign key constraint confusion (what is his job?)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, primary-key

I have followed a tutorial but I have a problem understanding couple lines of code below.

Suppose I have created these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
id smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
firstname varchar(30),
lastname varchar(30),
birthdate date,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
KEY idx_lastname (lastname)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE borrowed (
ref int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
employeeid smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
book varchar(50),
PRIMARY KEY (ref)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then I do some change for the borrowed table

```
ALTER TABLE borrowed 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_borrowed // line 1
FOREIGN KEY (employeeid) REFERENCES employee(id)  // line 2
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Line 1 add a constraint? what constraint?

Line 2 make the "employeeid" of borrowed table a foreign key which references to the "id" of employee table, that is all what this line of code doing, right?

So my question is what is meaning of line 1? It adds a constraint which contains nothing? I am new to MySQL.

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY` itself is a `CONSTRAINT`

Comment: the foreign key is defined as "employeeid"  in line 2, so? @PM77-1

Comment: Your whole statement add a FOREIGN KEY.

Answer (score 0):

Line 2 is simply an extension of line 1.  The foreign key is the constraint that is being added.

Comment: what is the difference between "employeeid" and "FK_borrowed", both of them are foreign key?

Comment: FK_borrowed is the name of the constraint/foreign key.  employeeid is the field being constrained.

Comment: Check the [docs](http://https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). The `[CONSTRAINT [symbol]]` portion is optional. The *symbol* is an identifier for the constraint, and must be unique within the database, but has no semantic meaning.  If you don't provide one, InnoDB will make one up for you.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
ALTER TABLE borrowed 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_borrowed // line 1
FOREIGN KEY (employeeid) REFERENCES employee(id)  // line 2
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Is the same as this:

```
ALTER TABLE borrowed ADD CONSTRAINT FK_borrowed FOREIGN KEY (employeeid) REFERENCES employee(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Your *Foreign Key* is a *Constraint*, `FK_borrowed` is its name, `employeeid` is the column in the table `borrowed`, `employee` and `id` are the table and column you're referencing, respectively.